# Is OnValidate too late to be making changes?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Every `OnValidate` example I seem to see is essentially read-only (checking values, and throwing exceptions). I would like to go a step further and *modify* values (where unambiguous fix-up is possible) as part of the validation process. Is the `OnValidate` callback too late in the pipeline for making modifications (without breaking other assumptions)? or otherwise discouraged?

For a (contrived) example, suppose I were to trim whitespace or coalesce null strings to empty strings in `OnValidate`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it depends on how you want it to work for the user.

You could possibly do it when the value changes (textchanged etc), or when the item loses focus.

OnValidate is for kind of showing an overall summary I guess.

Personally I would prefer that "my error is shown, but I make the change to get it correct".. eg predictive text on mobile phones it's Auto Correct is often wrong, but maybe I just type funny.